# How can I create a table in psql client?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have an existing Database which I can access with postico, and I want to migrate the structure to a new database which I can only access with psql.

Postico gives the SQL to re-create the table

> ```
> -- DDL generated by Postico 1.5.8
> -- Not all database features are supported. Do not use for backup.
>
> -- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------
>
> CREATE TABLE "Datas" (
>     id integer DEFAULT nextval('"Data_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
>     DataLabel character varying(255) NOT NULL,
>     DataValue character varying(255),
>     "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
>     "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
> );
>
> -- Indices -------------------------------------------------------
>
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Data_pkey" ON "Datas"(id int4_ops);
> CREATE INDEX datas_id ON "Datas"(id int4_ops);
> ```

But if I try to run the create table in the psql client I get the error

```
relation "Datas_id_seq" does not exist
```

How can I migrate the table structure across? Do I need to manually create the relation? if so how?

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Comment: Yeah you should use postgresql naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the sequence `"Data_id_seq"` first:

```
create sequence "Data_id_seq";
```

but the column was probably defined as `serial` originally:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Datas" (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    DataLabel character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    DataValue character varying(255),
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```